# Using for await...of with synchronous iterables

Tags: javascript, async-await

MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) `for await...of` has two use-cases:

> The `for await...of` statement creates a loop iterating over async
>   iterable objects as well as on sync iterables,...

I was previously aware of the former: async iterables using `Symbol.asyncIterator`. But I am now interested in the latter: synchronous iterables.

The following code iterates over a synchronous iterable - an array of promises. It appears to block progess on the fulfilment of each promise.

```js
async function asyncFunction() {
    try {
        const happy = new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(()=>resolve('happy'), 1000))
        const sad = new Promise((_,reject)=>setTimeout(()=>reject('sad')))
        const promises = [happy, sad]
        for await(const item of promises) {
            console.log(item)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`an error occurred:`, err)
    }
}

asyncFunction() // "happy, an error occurred: sad" (printed in quick succession, after about 5 seconds)
```

The behavior appears to be akin to awaiting each promise in-turn, per the logic shown below. Is this assertion correct?

```js
async function asyncFunction() {
    try {
        const happy = new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(()=>resolve('happy'), 1000))
        const sad = new Promise((_,reject)=>setTimeout(()=>reject('sad')))
        const promises = [happy, sad]
        for(let p of promises) {
            const item = await p
            console.log(item)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`an error occurred:`, err)
    }
}

asyncFunction() // "happy, an error occurred: sad" (printed in quick succession, after about 5 seconds)
```

I ask because this pattern of code has an implicit rejection wire-up pitfall that `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled` avoid, and it seems strange to me that this pattern would be explicitly supported by the language.

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', () => {
  console.log('unhandled rejection; `sad` was not being awaited at the time it rejected')
})

async function asyncFunction() {
    try {
        const happy = new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(()=>resolve('success'), 1000))
        const sad = new Promise((_,reject)=>setTimeout(()=>reject('failure')))
        const promises = [happy, sad]
        for(let p of promises) {
            const item = await p
            console.log(item)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`an error occurred:`, err)
    }
}

asyncFunction() // "unhandled rejection; `sad` was not being awaited at the time it rejected" (after about zero seconds), and then "happy, an error occurred: sad" (printed in quick succession, after about 5 seconds)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems like the examples you provided work

Comment: Is my description of `for await... of` with synchronous iterables, correct, and if so, does it matter that that pattern can emit unhandled rejection errors?

Comment: "Is it correct" isn't a question.  "Correct" is whatever you say it is.

Comment: Can you demonstrate via code the emitting of unhandled rejection errors that you described?

Comment: The final code demonstrates it. Correct has a well-defined meaning in this context because I have provided the code to describe what I think it is doing. If the behavior matches my code, then my code is correct, otherwise my understanding is incorrect. Also the observation _"Correct" is whatever you say it is._ is clearly untrue. Correct has a well defined meaning in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is strange, and you should not do this. Don't iterate arrays of promises, it leads [exactly to the unhandled-rejections problem you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889290/1048572). (See also [this more specific explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695815/10485).)

So why is this supported in the language? To continue with the sloppy promise semantics.

You can find the exact reasoning in [this comment of the issue discussing this part of the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/12#issuecomment-246403264):

> I think we should fall back to `Symbol.iterator` because our current
>   Promise semantics are all about allowing sync things to be used as
>   async things. You might call this "sloppiness". It follows
>   [@groundwater's logic above](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/12#issuecomment-157209898),
>   but I just want to spell out the parallels in more detail.
>
> The "chaining" semantics of `.then` are all about this. You can return a
>   Promise from `.then` or a scalar value; it's all the same. You call
>   `Promise.resolve` not to wrap something in a Promise, but to cast
>   something to a Promise--get an asynchronous value when you have
>   something-or-other.
>
> The semantics of `async` and `await` are all about being sloppy as well.
>   You can slap `await` on any non-Promise expression in an async function
>   and everything works fine, exactly the same way, except that you yield
>   control to the job queue. Similarly, you can "defensively" put `async`
>   around whatever you want, as long as you `await` the result. If you have
>   a function that returns a Promise--whatever! you can make that an
>   `async` function, and, from a user perspective, nothing changes (even
>   if, technically, you get a different Promise object out).
>
> Async iterators and generators should work the same way. Just like you
>   can await a value that, accidentally, wasn't a Promise, a reasonable
>   user would expect to be able to `yield*` a sync iterator within an async
>   generator. `for await` loops should similarly "just work" if a user
>   defensively marks a loop that way, thinking that they maybe might be
>   getting an async iterator.
>
> I think it would be a big deal to break all of these parallels. It
>   would make async iterators less ergonomic. Let's discuss this the next
>   time async generators/iterators come up on the agenda at TC39.

Comment: Thank you. Is an event emitted, or is it actually some other kind of error? I ask because I thought events were part of the WebAPI. Is emission of events used in a similar fashion, in other parts of the spec?

Comment: @52d6c6af Are you referring to the `unhandledrejection` events?

Comment: Yes. It's just that to intercept the "error" I used `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection',...` In short: it is the only instance I can bring to mind, of this kind of error emission by JavaScript. I'm almost certainly wrong to think this, however. Finally: does the emission of this "error" ever really matter beyond having an unwanted error message in the console?

Comment: @52d6c6af See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58922592/1048572) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57261820/1048572) for how this is specified in a joint effort between ECMAScript and Web API specs. No, the event doesn't really matter, it's too late already when you got this. Afaics, it is only used for monitoring client-side errors.

Comment: If it doesn't really matter, is the advice still "do not iterate arrays of promises", or is it rather "be aware that this does not exhibit fail-fast behavior under some circumstances"?

Comment: @52d6c6af I meant that handling the event doesn't really matter, as there's not much you can do about the problem in the event handler. I still consider it an error, and a programmer mistake to write such code. In node.js, it could crash your application just like an unhandled exception.

Comment: But wrapping the `for await...of` in a `try...catch` still catches the error, albeit after the promises preceding the rejected promise, have resolved. My point is that the error can still be handled - just at a different time.

Comment: Not after your application already has crashed from the unhandled rejection. Just don't do it.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the language design here because a lot of devs will guess that `for await...of` is for enumerating promises, and even worse - it kind-of works!

Comment: @Bergi I get a feeling you don't think `for await... of` has much of use. Am I right ? I am struggling with a practical use of it.

Comment: @Qiulang `for await … of` is useful where the sequence itself is generated asynchronously (and where its length is not known beforehand to the consumer). A perfect example is paginated fetching of a list from an api. Less perfect would be reading files from a large directory - while one could write that code in two steps (getting an array of filenames, then iterating that), sometimes you prefer an api surface that has them packed in one: an asynchronous iterator where you always get filename and contents together.

Comment: @Bergi I asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103606/some-practical-example-of-asynchronous-iterationfor-await-of-in-action. In my question I did mention paginated fetching is one example of using `for await of`. Maybe you can just answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

The `sad` promise *isn't* being `await`ed when it fails - that code needs to finish waiting on `happy` before it can begin to wait on `sad`. The `sad` promise is failing before `happy` resolves. (`Promise.all` is a tool better suited to this use-case)

Comment: I know. Hence my question. If `Promise.all` is a better solution, why does the language cater for this syntax? `for await...of` could easily have been implemented to simply enumerate asynchronous iterables. But they catered for it to enumerate synchronous iterables (but with a (seeming?) pitfall). Why?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Are we asking why `for await ... of` accepts synchronous iterables? I'd imagine to support async generators which conditionally may return synchronous items.

Comment: Yes, especially so given that it appears to introduce a rejection wire-up pitfall.

Comment: In my opinion the pitfall is more generally in creating a promise, and not awaiting it immediately. Unfortunately this pitfall is also often a very useful feature.