# Some practical example of asynchronous iteration(for-await-of) in action?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I know what [asynchronous iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) is. But ever since MDN & node.js 10 introduced it in 2018 I have yet to see its practical use, e.g. what kind of problem would be better solved by it? [A common example](https://zaiste.net/posts/nodejs-10-asynchronous-iteration-async-generators/) I see is to rewrite the callback fs.createReadStream to `for await (const chunk of stream)`

[Another example](https://blog.risingstack.com/async-iterators-in-node-js/) I can think of is to sending paginated requests in sequence.

But these 2 examples are not compelling enough to convince me using `for-await-of`. I just can not think of a scenario that I have an array of promises that I need to resolve them one by one.

So can someone give some practical example of using asynchronous iteration to solve a problem better than without it?

Comment: I know what you mean, just like callback hell, an async thing depends of the result of another async thing. But my problem is I can't think of a scenario that I can get all promises beforehand and for await of them one by one.

Comment: @danh check the answer I got here https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/135

Comment: "*a scenario where I have an array of promises*" - it's too late when you already have all the promises (a fixed number of them) in an array; in that case, [you should not use `for await … of`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60706179/1048572). Asynchronous iteration is only useful where the promises are *created* one after another, e.g. when it depends on the result of the previous item, and it allows you to start processing the first without seeing the end.

Comment: "*These examples are not compelling enough to convince me using `for-await-of`.*" - can you show us how you would write code for those without `for await … of`? Maybe it is easier to explain the difference then. But yes, it's mostly just syntactic sugar, you can write any such loop by manually iterating over a structure with `await getNext()` - just like `for … of` is just syntactic sugar, and like every `for` loop can be rewritten as `while`.

Comment: @Bergi "it's too late when you already have all the promises" I asked this question first before I saw your answer there. But for your answer there I don't have a clear idea why it is too late then if I really want to resolve them one by one ?

Comment: @Qiulang Because promises are not resolved from the outside, they don't "start resolving when you await them" - the tasks you execute start when you create the promise, the promise just represents the result. So "*resolve them one by one*" makes no sense. You can only "***create** them one by one*".

Comment: Oh right! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an answer by just quoting words from @Bergi's comments and from the comments I got from https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/135. Without an answer my question will be auto-deleted because it has got down-voted.

@Bergi comments from his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60707105/301513

> for await … of is useful where the sequence itself is generated
> asynchronously (and where its length is not known beforehand to the
> consumer). A perfect example is paginated fetching of a list from an
> api. Less perfect would be reading files from a large directory -
> while one could write that code in two steps (getting an array of
> filenames, then iterating that), sometimes you prefer an api surface
> that has them packed in one: an asynchronous iterator where you always
> get filename and contents together.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/135 gives an example for reading files from a large directory,

```
import fs from "fs/promises";

async function* findAllFiles(directory: string) {
    const dirEntries = await fs.readdir(directory, { withFileTypes: true });
    for (const dirEntry of dirEntries) {
        if (dirEntry.isFile()) {
            yield path.join(directory, dirEntry.name);
        } else if (dirEntry.isDirectory()) {
            yield* findAllFiles(path.join(directory, dirEntry.name));
        }
    }
}

for await (const file of findAllFiles("/")) {
    if (file.match(/that-file-i-was-looking-for/)) {
        console.log(`Found it!`);
        console.log(file);
        break;
    }
}
```

To quote

> What makes these particularly better than doing it via loading all the
> entries into an array and returning a Promise for the array, is that
> they aren't actually all stored at once so if the list is extremely
> long (such as can be the case for entire file systems) you only
> actually receive one item at a time, the memory usage is merely the
> directory depth rather than the number of files.
>
> Another advantage of this approach, is that you don't process what you
> don't need, when break is used in the above loop the generator
> function actually just stops. It won't continue past the last file
> which was yield-ed, and as such we don't wind up searching the entire
> file system if we find what we need early on.

---  update ---

6 months later I have a better understanding of asynchronous iteration. Now I see that consuming data using `for await...of` is nicely separated from the asynchronous generator, each on its own can be a straightforward implementation. And I am not always the author of these 2 parts.

BTW, https://www.nodejsdesignpatterns.com/blog/javascript-async-iterators/ gives the most detailed information about async iterator I have read.