# Run The Build Synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I couldn't get my for loop to run synchronously.The order of registration that it returns for each domain changes. I guess whichever answers the fastest brings those records first. Where am I doing wrong?

```
const rrtypes= ["A","MX","CNAME","NS","TXT"];
var resData = [];
    
export const getAllRecords = async (req,res) => {
    const {domain} = req.params;
         for await(const rrtype of rrtypes){
             dns.resolve (domain, rrtype, (err, records) => { 
             resData.push(rrtype+" "+records);
        });
    }    
        res.send(resData);
        resData = [];      
}
```

Comment: Don't use `async`/`await` if you want to run it synchronously? And [never use `for await … of` on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60706179/1048572)!

Comment: Did you mean you want to run the loop *sequentially*? Then you need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the `dns.resolve` call, and `await` *that*.

Comment: Also move the `var resData = [];` inside your function declaration, or else the array would be shared between multiple calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you can use the `dns.promises.resolve` function: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dnspromises_resolve_hostname_rrtype

so you would change your code to:

```js
const rrtypes = ["A", "MX", "CNAME", "NS", "TXT"];

export const getAllRecords = async (req, res) => {
  const { domain } = req.params;

  // Notice that resData should be local to this function
  let resData = [];
  for (const rrtype of rrtypes) {
    try {
      const records = await dns.promises.resolve(domain, rrtype);
      resData.push(rrtype + " " + records);
      // IMO this would be better: resData.push({ type: rrtype, value: records });
    } catch (err) {
      // Log the error here
    }
  }

  res.send(resData);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your use of `await`. `await` should be used when calling async functions. At the moment you are using it when instantiating variables from an array.

Thanks to a comment by slebetman I was able to see this `dns.resolve` does not return a promise but uses callbacks to manage the async calls. As he also suggested we can fix this by creating a promise to manage these callbacks.

```
const rrtypes= ["A","MX","CNAME","NS","TXT"];
var resData = [];

const dnsResolvePromise = (domain, rrtype) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dns.resolve(domain, rrtype, (err, records) => { 
        if(err) return reject(err);
        resolve(rrtype+" "+records);
    });
  })
}

export const getAllRecords = async (req,res) => {
    const {domain} = req.params;
    for(const rrtype of rrtypes){
        try{
            const records = await dnsResolvePromise(domain, rrtype);
            resData.push(records);
       } catch (e){
         // Handle error
       }
    }    
    res.send(resData);
    resData = [];      
}
```

Comment: It's a standard node.js function: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve_hostname_rrtype_callback. And NO, it DOES NOT return a promise. You will have to show him how to wrap callbacks in promises

Comment: @slebetman Ah thanks for pointing this out to me, I did not know this before.

Comment: or you can use the already built in `dns.promises.resolve` which uses promise and not callback so you do not need a helper functionn to convert callbacks to promises

Comment: This will keep them in order but it will also be slow as it waits for each promise before running the next

Comment: @Dominic, that is true, alternatively `Promise.all` make them in parallel