# Difference between 'for of' and 'for await of'

Tags: javascript

Here is a timer function

```
const timer = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`${time} timer start`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${time} timer end`);
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });
};
```

I'm going to call this timer function with 'for await of` and 'for of'.

First, 'for await of'

```
async function runForAwaitOf() {
  const times = [300, 100, 700, 500];

  for await (let time of times) {
      await timer(time);
  }

  console.log('All the timers end');
}
runForAwaitOf()
```

Second, 'for of'

```
async function runForOf() {
  const times = [300, 100, 700, 500];

  for (let time of times) {
      await timer(time);
  }

  console.log('All the timers end');
}
runForOf()
```

When I ran above codes, I don't see any differences between them.

If they results the sames, why does ECMA make `for await of`?

Comment: `for...await of` is about handling async iterators, not just handling iterables of promises.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#description MDN explains the differences quite well, just look for the list of differences in the description

Comment: Related: [for await of VS Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59694309) | [Using for await...of with synchronous iterables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60706179)

Comment: @VLAZ I'd even close as a duplicate, would you disagree?

Comment: @Bergi I won't disagree.

Answer (score 7):

`for await` can be used for consuming *async iterables*. It can also consume standard iterables (like the one in your question) - but with standard iterables, it won't appear any different from using `for..of`.

For an example of an async iterable for which `for await` could be useful:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function* multiTimer() {
  await delay(1000);
  yield 1;
  await delay(2000);
  yield 2;
  await delay(3000);
  yield 3;
  await delay(1000);
  yield 4;
};
(async () => {
  for await (const time of multiTimer()) {
      console.log('got', time);
  }
  console.log('All the timers end');
})();
```

If you have a standard iterable, you should use `for..of`, and if you have an async iterable, you should use `for await..of`. They're designed for different situations.